# Export RGB data (from a tiff image) in excel format

Tags: raster, r, excel, rgb

I have a **tiff** file having 3 bands R, G, B. I used the following program in R to obtain the pixel values for each band separately.

```
r<- raster("lena.tiff", band = 1)
writeRaster(r, filename = "lenadd.asc", format = "ascii", datatype= 'INT4U')
```

It gave me an ascii file containing the pixel values for R band. Similarly, by changing the band value to 2 and 3, I can get the other two files. However, I want to export the data in excel format. But I suppose, **writeRaster** command doesn't support xlsx format. So, can someone please suggest me any alternative of writeRaster command so that I can export my RGB data in excel format?

I am new to R so pardon me if the question is too trivial.

Edited :

class       : RasterLayer

band        : 1  (of  3  bands)

dimensions  : 512, 512, 262144  (nrow, ncol, ncell)

resolution  : 1, 1  (x, y)

extent      : 0, 512, 0, 512  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)

coord. ref. : NA

data source : C:\Users\lenovo\Documents\lena.tiff

names       : lena

values      : 0, 255  (min, max)

Comment: You should probably explain a bit more how you want the data formatted i Excel - do you want the data laid out in a grid, with a new sheet for each lf the channels? Or as a single sheet with five columns - row number, column number, R, G, B values?

Comment: @Spacedman I want the data laid out in a grid with a new sheet for each of the channels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a function that uses `raster` and `xlsx` packages to write a multi-band raster to an Excel spreadsheet, one band per sheet, in a gridded format:

```
stack_to_xlsx <- function(rs, filename){
    w = createWorkbook()
    for(i in 1:nlayers(rs)){
        cs = createSheet(w, sheetName = paste0("Band-",i))
        dr = raster::as.data.frame(raster::as.matrix(raster(rs,i)))
        addDataFrame(
            dr,
            cs
            )
    }
    saveWorkbook(w, filename)
}
```

And here's a usage:

Use `stack` to read in all the bands:

```
> rs = stack("./preston.tiff")
```

This is quite a large tiff so I crop it down a bit:

```
> rsc = stack(crop(rs, extent(350172.7, 351308.5, 429508.1, 430840 )))
> dim(rsc)
[1] 118 100   4
> stack_to_xlsx(rsc, "crop.xls")
>
```

Now open `crop.xls` in Excel (Or OpenOffice, that also works).

Comment: The program runs but there isn't any file exported.

Comment: How did you load the tiff? What dimension was it? How did you run the `stack_to_xls` function? What *exactly* did you type?

Comment: sorry, got it..